# Word matching to string

Tags: python

I'm trying to do some word/string matching with a string to a category. I have created a simple example of what I am trying to do and the problem I am having.

I am trying to match based on words and give a category a point for a match and then choose the category with the highest match.

The problem being more than one category can have the highest value and my code just chooses the first one from the list. It seems wrong to get them two items and then start checking through the dictionary again.

Could someone advice me if I am going in the right direction with how I am doing this or if there is a better way?

```
categorys = {
    'fruits': ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'pear'],
    'chocolate': ['mars', 'kitkat', 'areo'],
    'drinks': ['coffee', 'tea', 'orange', 'coke']
}

# create a diction of points for each category and set to 0
points = {}
for key, value in categorys.items():
    points[key] = 0

# calulate points for category
# key = category, value = style
for key, values in categorys.items():
    if 'orange' in key.lower() or 'drink' in values:
        points[key] += 1

# get category with the highest point although it just grabs the first item
calculated_category = max(points.iterkeys(), key=(lambda key: points[key]))
print calculated_category
```

**Edit**

Updated code from answers

```
    categorys = {
    'fruits': ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'pear'],
    'chocolate': ['mars', 'kitkat', 'areo'],
    'drinks': ['coffee', 'tea', 'orange', 'coke']
}

# create a diction of points for each category and set to 0
points = {}
for key, value in categorys.items():
    points[key] = 0

# calulate points for category
# key = category, value = style
for key, values in categorys.items():
    if 'drink' in key.lower()
        points[key] += 1
    if 'orange' in values:
        points[key] += 1

# get category with the highest point although it just grabs the first     item
# max(points.iterkeys(), key=(lambda key: points[key]))
max_value = max(points.values())
[k for k, v in points.iteritems() if v == max_value]
```

Comment: what is output you expecting from this input?

Comment: I'm confused about where `orange` and `drink` are coming from, especially since you seem to be testing them against the opposite parts of the `categorys` dict (`drink in key` and `orange in values` would both be true some of the time, but the given conditions never will be). It might make sense to reverse your categories dictionary, if you're going to be looking up terms like `orange` often: `{"orange": ["fruits", "drinks"]}` can be used directly, without iterating over lots of unnecessary stuff.

Comment: I have a flow of data coming from someone else which I can't change. Each word can actually match up with the key/value in multiple ways.

Comment: @VivekSable i was expecting to get the key 'Drinks'

Comment: ok, suppose `orange` is element and according to it we have to give points to keys from the dictionary. As `orange` in `fruits` and `drinks` so points of  `fruits' is `1` , `chocolate` is `0` and `drinks` is `1` then on which logic expecting output is `drinks` ?

Comment: @VivekSable I guess that is the question. I would expect drinks but because of the two matches I'm either getting both fruits and drinks or just fruits (because of ordering). Maybe I should split up the two checks and increment on separate matches?

Comment: "I would expect drinks" But _why_ would you expect drinks? What is your input? Just `orange`, or `orange` and `drink`? In the latter case, why do you need to match at all, since one of the inputs seems to be the category already?

Comment: I'd expect drinks because drinks has two matches in the key and value, whereas fruits only has one match in the value. I am trying to split up the checks into two if statements and incrementing points on a match of either instead of both.

Comment: @lennard You're iterating over key-value pairs. That means even if your `value` is `orange drink`, that key-value pair is iterated only once. So the count would increment only once.

Comment: @mogambo I've added what i meant by incrementing twice.

Comment: ok means input is both key and value i.e. `drink` and `orange` . correct? If input is 'orange` and `vegetables`  what will be output?

Comment: I guess then we will get fruits and drinks. But i've never done anything like this before, so I'm not sure what to do in this situation. I don't have control over the data I get inputted, but i need to try and calculate the the category from the two values I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `max` to get the maximum `points` value, and then use a list comprehension to get all the item that have that value.

```
max_value = max(points.values())
calculated_category = [k for k, v in points.iteritems() if v == max_value]
print calculated_category
```

Output is `['fruits', 'drinks', 'chocolate']`, as in your example, they all seem to have the same `points` value of `0`; not sure if this is intentional or another problem. If you change the condition to `if 'drink' in key.lower() or 'orange' in values:`, which seems to make more sense, then output is `['fruits', 'drinks']`.

Comment: Ah interesting, yeah they all have 0 to start with as a start then increment on a match (that's the idea).

Comment: So it outputs fruits and drinks, when really I only want to see 'Drinks'. Do I need to then loop through these again to decide which is the correct category? Or is there a better way?

Comment: It outputs all the values that have the highest value. I though that's what you wanted. If instead you are looking for a different metric for finding the "best match" (by what criteria?) you should elaborate that in your question. What is the word you are trying to categorize anyway? There are two words in your condition -- "orange" and "drink".

Comment: Thanks, I think with everyones help and comments I have got a bit futher to where I want to be.

Answer (score 0):

I am considering that your inputs will be something like:-

1. fruits, banana
2. drinks, tea....etc.

You can proceed as:-

```
cat, item = raw_input()  #you enter fruits, banana
for key, values in categorys.items():
    if cat == key.lower() and item in values:
        points[key] += 1

# get category with the highest point although it just grabs the first item
calculated_category = max(points.items(), key = lambda item_tuple: item_tuple[1])
print calculated_category
```

Answer (score 0):

Just some addition points in code:

1. **Dictionary comprehension** to create dictionary:

Demo:

```
>>> points = { key:0 for key in categorys }
>>> points
{'fruits': 0, 'drinks': 0, 'chocolate': 0}
>>>
```

---

2. Use **collection** module to create default int dictionary

No need to assign `0` value to every key. [Link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html)

Demo:

```
>>> import collections
>>> points = collections.defaultdict(int)
>>> points["drink"]
0
>>> points["drink"] += 1
>>> points["drink"]
1
```

---

3. Use `iteritems()` method to iterate key and value dictionary (`iteams()`  will return list of tuple)

Comment: @lennard: Welcome. Free to ask question on Stackoverflow. You can also shear you issue and knowledge with me vivekbsable@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to have many words like `"orange"` and `"drink"` that you want to test against your categories, I suggest making another dict that maps from the words to a list of categories (the reverse of your current dict). This will let you do very quick tests to see what categories (if any) a word is in, without lots of iteration.

```
from collections import Counter

categorys = {
    'fruits': ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'pear'],
    'chocolate': ['mars', 'kitkat', 'areo'],
    'drinks': ['coffee', 'tea', 'orange', 'coke']
}

words_to_cats = {}
for cat, words in categorys.items():
    for word in words:
        words_to_cats.setdefault(word, []).append(cat)

def find_best_category(iterable_of_words):
    score = Counter()
    for word in iterable_of_words:
        score.update(words_to_cats.get(word, [])) # count matches in the word list

        for cat in categorys: # check for partial matches in the category name
            if word in cat:
                score[cat] += 1

    return score.most_common(1)
```

Note that this will wtill return just a single item, and if there's an exact tie, it will pick a winning category arbitrarily among the ones with the highest scores. In your example (with an input of `['orange', 'drink']`), there is no tie and it will pick `"drinks"`, since both of the words are matched to that category (one to the word "orange" and one in a partial match to the category name).